# Using ID as authentication hash

Tags: php, mysql, hash, user-registration

I have a website that gives each user a unique ID when they register. They also then get a hash number for verification.

This is all fine but I was just wondering if it would be wrong to use the unique ID for the hash instead of having a separate column with another unique number stored in there.

What are your thoughts and opinions?

Comment: It depends. FYI Stackoverflow is not really for thoughts and opinions.

Comment: there are a dozen was to interpret this question

Answer (score 0):

Someone trying hard enough could figure out the relationship between the ID and hash. A simple solution would be to use a long salt when hashing.